# .htaccess rewrite not working with my site

Tags: .htaccess

I have been trying to rewrite a url like this:

```
/gallery/test.php?id=1
```

to this:

```
/gallery/test/1
```

However it isn't working. I have url rewriting enabled and have used phpinfo() to check.

this is my code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Multiviews

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^test/([0-9]+)/?$ test.php?id=$1 [NC,L]    
</IfModule>
```

Comment: what do you mean by doesnt work? Do you get an error? does it do anything at all? do you get 404? Be specific. Also where is you .htaccess located?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need a rewrite base. Try adding the following on the line after the `RewriteEngine on` line.

```
RewriteBase /gallery/
```

Comment: Options +FollowSymLinks -Multiviews

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
    RewriteEngine on
 RewriteBase /gallery/
 RewriteRule ^test/([0-9]+)/?$ test.php?id=$1 [NC,L]    
</IfModule> I changed it to this and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

this is a rewrite rule that should work

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^gallery/test/([^/]*)$ /gallery/test.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't work. I think maybe the url rewrite is not enabled but this variable: _SERVER["HTTP_MOD_REWRITE"] is set to "On"